# Is it possible to retrieve one string between 2 special characters from text file using bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Let's say I have the following text file

```
test.txt
ABC_01:Testing-ABCDEFG
```

If I want to retrieve the string after colon, I will be using

```
awk -F ":" '/ABC_01/{print $NF}' test.txt
```

which will return `Testing-ABCDEFG`

But what should I do if I only want to retrieve the string **after the colon** and **before the hyphen**?

Comment: `awk -F '[:-]' '/ABC_01/{print $2}'`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Sir, what if I want to replace ```ABC_01``` with a ```variable``` that store ```ABC_01```? I've tried ```awk -F '[:-]' '/$varName/{print $2}'``` but it doesn't work

Comment: I found it, ```awk -F '[:-]' '/'$varName'/{print $2}'```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are so close. That is where `split()` comes in, e.g.

```
awk -F: '/ABC_01/{ split($NF,arr,"-"); print arr[1] }'
```

Which will output

```
Testing
```

The [GNU Awk User's Guide - String Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) provides the details on `split()`. Give it a try and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Alternatively: `awk '{ match($0, /:(.*)-/, m); print m[1] }'`

Comment: Yes, that is a very nice approach too.

Comment: or `sed -n 's/.*:\(.*\)-.*/\1/p'`

Comment: Probably still want the match `/ABC_01/` before either expressions and for `sed` since the match will be greedy, you probably want `sed -n '/ABC_01/s/^[^:]*:\(.*\)-.*/\1/p'`

Answer (score 2):

Using Bash's built'in Extended Regex Engine

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r; do
  [[ $REPLY =~ :(.*)- ]] || :
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

Using standard POSIX shell `IFS` field separators:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while IFS=':-' read -r _ m _; do
  echo "$m"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Using (GNU) grep and look-around:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=:)[^-]*(?=-)' file
Testing
```

Explained:

- `grep` GNU grep supports PCRE and look-around
- `-o *Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line*
- `-P` *Interpret   PATTERNS   as  Perl-compatible  regular  expressions*
- `(?<=:)` positive look-behind, ie. *preceeded by a colon*
- `[^-]*` anything but a hyphen
- `(?=-)` positive look-ahead, ie. *followed by a hyphen*